# Trying to write numpy array (generated through a loop) into csv format

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have a code that generates a 1-D numpy array in each iteration. I want the arrays to get appended to the end of a CSV file so that I can read all data from Excel. I am currently trying the following method:

```
for loop in range(0,10):
    # The following part generates the array 
    Array1 = numpy.array([4.3])  
    Array2 = numpy.array([10.2])
    Array3 = numpy.concatenate((Array1,Array2),axis=0)

    # The following part tries to generate a CSV writable array. But it fails :S
    if (loop == 0):
        ArrayMain = Array3
    else:
        # Trying to append the new array with the previous array
        ArrayMain = numpy.asarray(ArrayMain,Array3)  

# Trying to write the array into a .txt. file in .csv format
numpy.savetxt("ArrayMain.csv", ArrayMain, delimiter=",",fmt='%.3f')
```

This code is giving errors. Any idea how I can rectify it?

Comment: Which errors is it giving you?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use append function to append new array with previous array, asarray function converts input to array.

```
    else:
        # Trying to append the new array with the previous array
        ArrayMain = numpy.append(ArrayMain,Array3)
```

Comment: Yes, error was on `ArrayMain = numpy.asarray(ArrayMain,Array3)` line.

Answer (score 1):

You should really keep in mind that `ndarrays` are not really designed to be appended like that.

If you write your CSV file at once outside of the loop, you should consider using a list of arrays instead.

```
base = []
for i in range(10):
    base.append(...)
np.savetxt("ArrayMain.csv", base, ...)
```

That'll work provided the arrays you append to `base` have all the same size (`np.savext` will transform the list of arrays into an array itself).

Alternatively, you could open the file you want to write first, then use its handle in `np.savetxt` to update it at each iteration. In that case, don't forget to close it at the end...

Answer (score 0):

Mostafar is right. numpy.asarray does not append lists

```
numpy.asarray([1,2]) -> array([1,2])
```

i.e. what it actually does is that it converts a list to an array. 
You can use the append function as he has defined. Or my personal favourite

numpy.r_

Usage:

```
numpy.r_[array([1,2]), array([3,4])] -> array([1,2,3,4])

also:

numpy.r_[array([1,2]), 3, [4,5], 6, array([7,8])] -> array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])
```

as you can see it can be used to concatenate various lists, arrays and single elements at one go.